# javascript prevent cursor to move

Tags: javascript, preventdefault, stoppropagation

Into an input box, I want to **stop the propagation of the cursor** just as I type on the up key "↑" :

Before :

`tes|t` // cursor is before *t*

After :

`|test` // cursor went beginning

I want to prevent the cursor to move, so it has to stay before *t*.

So far, I'm trying with this, but it doesn't work :

```
$('input').keyup(function(e) {

    if (e.which == 40) { // up key
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        // actions

        return false;
    }

}
```

Is this possible anyway ?

Comment: Try keydown instead of keyup.

Comment: That's probably not a good idea. I personally rely on this behaviour when typing (albeit rarely)...

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: That works just great with keydown :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`keydown`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) for that:

```
$('input').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 40) { // up key
        return false;
    }
}
```

`keyup` fires after the `keypress` event has been handled and `keypress` is supposed to not fire for non-printable characters (though there are some inconsistencies across different browsers), so preventing the event's default action right at `keydown` is the best course of action.

Keep in mind that if you don't have a good reason for preventing the default action (e.g. going through an autocomplete list while having the search field focused), you may be affecting other users' usability as commented by @Kolink.

Comment: Just to be exact, `keypress` doesn't fire for non-printable characters in any browser, though there are some differences, which characters are counted as printable, between browsers.

Comment: @Teemu I'm aware that `keypress` is supposed to not fire for non-printable characters, but in fact it does for Chrome.

Comment: @Teemu Strange, just tested in latest stable Chrome and it no longer fires the `keypress` event for arrow keys. Well, updated the answer to clean up that. `=]`

Comment: There really are some inconsistencies across different browsers, for example FF19 and IE10 fires `onkeypress` for `ESC` (how to print it?), but Chrome25 doesn't... +1 anyway : ).

Comment: Many years later but this isn't working for me (Chrome on OS X)